# Shortcut in BIDS to deploy only the current report (SSRS)?

Tags: reporting-services, keyboard-shortcuts, bids

I just found a shortcut in BIDS that is called `Build.DeploySelection` , and for this  I assigned <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and it worked.

But it deploys ALL my reports , even tho I only want it to do the one i'm working on.[image]

Comment: Does it only deploy the solution you want when you aren't doing it through the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @Neil - Yes, when I point at it and RT click

Comment: Ok. Another simple question. Do you have the solution highlighted (just like you do in the screenshot) when you do the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @Neil - Yes, I just tried it again also; and it will run all of the reports. Hmm, I'll keep at it. Thanks!!